# Table transformation: from list to presence/absence

Tags: r

I am looking for a solution to transform this table:

```
____V1______V2______V3______V4______V5______V6
1:  SP1     SP2     SP3      NA      NA      NA
2:  SP1     SP3     SP6      NA      NA      NA
3:  SP3     SP5     SP7      SP8     SP9     SP10
4:  SP4     SP5     SP6      SP7     NA      NA
```

into this one (presence/absence per species) :

```
___SP1___SP2___SP3___SP4___SP5___SP6___SP7___SP8___SP9___SP10
1:   1     1     1     0     0     0     0     0     0      0
2:   1     0     1     0     0     1     0     0     0      0
3:   0     0     1     0     1     0     1     1     1      1
4:   0     0     0     1     1     1     1     0     0      0
```

According that I have a lot of lines in table 1 and a lot of species (I don't know how many).

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer using reshape2:

```
data <- read.table(text="V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 
                   1: SP1 SP2 SP3 NA NA NA 
                   2: SP1 SP3 SP6 NA NA NA 
                   3: SP3 SP5 SP7 SP8 SP9 SP10 
                   4: SP4 SP5 SP6 SP7 NA NA")

#identify lines
data$line <- 1:nrow(data)
#turn data into long format
melt_data <- melt(data,id.var="line", variable.name="column",
                  value.name="species")
#rearrange levels species as otherwise SP10 comes after SP1
melt_data$species_fact <- factor(melt_data$species, 
                                    levels=paste0("SP",1:10))

#turn into - different- wide format for result
result <- dcast(data=melt_data[!is.na(melt_data$species_fact),],
                formula=line~species_fact,value.var="species_fact",
                fun.aggregate=length)
result
```

yields

```
> result
  line SP1 SP2 SP3 SP4 SP5 SP6 SP7 SP8 SP9 SP10
1    1   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0    0
2    2   1   0   1   0   0   1   0   0   0    0
3    3   0   0   1   0   1   0   1   1   1    1
4    4   0   0   0   1   1   1   1   0   0    0
```

Answer (score 5):

Try

```
library(qdapTools)
res1 <- mtabulate(as.data.frame(t(df1)))
```

Or

```
library(reshape2)
res2 <- table(melt(as.matrix(df1), na.rm=TRUE)[,-2])
res2New <- res2[,paste0('SP',1:10)]
res2New
#     value
# Var1 SP1 SP2 SP3 SP4 SP5 SP6 SP7 SP8 SP9 SP10
#   1   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0    0
#   2   1   0   1   0   0   1   0   0   0    0
#   3   0   0   1   0   1   0   1   1   1    1
#   4   0   0   0   1   1   1   1   0   0    0
```

If we need to convert to 'data.frame'

```
 as.data.frame.matrix(res2New)
```

#### data

```
 df1 <- structure(list(V1 = c("SP1", "SP1", "SP3", "SP4"), V2 = c("SP2", 
 "SP3", "SP5", "SP5"), V3 = c("SP3", "SP6", "SP7", "SP6"), V4 = c(NA, 
 NA, "SP8", "SP7"), V5 = c(NA, NA, "SP9", NA), V6 = c(NA, NA, 
 "SP10", NA)), .Names = c("V1", "V2", "V3", "V4", "V5", "V6"), 
 class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Comment: @RémyPoncet  Glad to know that it works.  The second one returns a `table` class.  You can convert it to data.frame with `as.data.frame.matrix(res2)`

Comment: Yes, I just saw it! It's perfect and very helpful! Thank you!

Comment: I thin akruns solution is better; mine is a bit elaborate.

Comment: @Heroka It's okay.  I think the OP liked your solution better :-)